# Database Schema Mapping of IntelliJ Persistence tool is empty

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, persistence

I already assign data source and get these table, but I still can not Mapping my Column name (like the picture)
How should I do it?
I'm using H2 DB.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried to click on "Refresh" button? Also please check idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") for errors/warnings.

Comment: I tried it, but still the same problem

Comment: What about log? Are there any related records?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have only selected the "current schema" - which is the one you used to create your datasource/connection.  You need to add/select the owning schema for the objects you wish to map.

**OPTION 1** -
**During Datasource Setup:**
[Data Sources and Drivers Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sam04.png)
Select the "Schemas" tab (the tool opens on the "General" tab) and choose the schema under which the object you are looking to map exists.

**OPTION 2** -
**After Datasource Setup**
You can follow the instructions for new datasource setup if you can get back to the window where you initially set up the datasource, however, there is a shortcut.  If you were able to successfully create a datasource, you should see that data source in the IntelliJ "Database Tool Window" (View > Tool Windows > Database).  There is a small pill icon that you can interact with.  Mine says "3 of 2195" - this is telling you that you have visibility of 3 schemas of a total 2195 available. Click the pill icon.  Find the schema that owns the table you need to map and select it.

**After Option 1 OR 2**
You should then be able to navigate to the persistence tool, right click your project, and select "Generate Persistence Mapping", then click "By Database Schema".  Once you select a datasource in the "Import Database Schema Window" you should see all the objects(tables) available for mapping.

NOTE:
I am running IntelliJ Ultimate Edition v2020.1. I am connecting and mapping objects from an enterprise Oracle 12c database (can't really share screenshots so I will try to be descriptive)

I know I was pulling my hair out so I hope someone finds this helpful!